# interpolate data series with R

Tags: r, interpolation

I am having trouble interpolating the values of two data series. I have a reference time in first column. The second column is time linked for values of P130. I want to interpolate new values of P130 (third column) according to reference time.

The reference time and timeP130 have the first and last value the same and they are all in variable steps, so there is no pattern.

```
Reference_time  timeP130    P130  results
0.0001          0.0001  0.2194    0.2194
0.000694        0.003   0.25      0.22552
0.00138889      0.0035  0.26      0.23164
0.00208333      0.006   0.24      0.23776
0.00277778      0.009   0.245     0.24388
0.003           0.009   0.255     0.25
0.00416667      0.0125  0.27      ETC 
0.00486111      0.015   0.21
0.00555556      0.018   0.20
0.00625         0.0208  0.2194
0.00694444      0.021   0.2194
0.00763889      0.0211  0.2194
0.00833333      0.0215  0.2194
0.00902778      0.022   0.2195
0.00972222      0.0327  0.2591
0.0104167       0.0433  0.3664
0.0111111       0.0839  0.4068
0.0118056       2.5     0.4087
0.0125                            0.27
0.0141944   
0.0158889   
0.0165833   
0.0182778   
2.5                               0.4087
```

Comment: have a look at `approxfun`, it's not mentionned which kind of interpolation you want to perform..

Comment: i have variable data steps in the first and second column. only the first and last value are the same for instance. so i want to interpolate second column (their respected values are in third column) in respect to first one?